# bounding the size of coefficients in ``almost orthogonal" basis representation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose $\{e_j\}_{1\leq j \leq 1}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$, and $\{y_i\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ is another basis with the properties
$$\|y_i\|=1 \forall i$$
$$c<|\angle(y_i,y_j)| <180-c\,\,\,\,\forall i$$
For some constant $c \in (0,90)$.  Suppose that $Z \in \mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$ has basis representations
$$\sum_i b_iy_i = z = \sum_i z_ie_i$$
I want to show that $|b_i|$ is small on the order of $\|z\|$, with a constant depending on $c$.  I am quite stuck at the moment and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for some function $f$ such that $|b_i| \leq f(c)\|z\|$? (loosely interpreting your last line, this is what I think you're asking)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am seeking.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$\left( y_1,y_2,\cdots ,y_n \right) =\left( e_1,e_2\cdots ,e_n \right) A$$

where $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ is an invertible matrix.

Thus we can get $y_i=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ki}e_k$.

So $\sum_{i=1}^{n}z_ie_i=\boldsymbol {z}=\sum_{i=1}^nb_iy_i=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ki}e_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^nb_ia_{ki}e_k$.

Then $z_k=\sum_{i=1}^nb_ia_{ki}$ i.e. $\boldsymbol {z}=A \boldsymbol {b}$
$~~$where $\boldsymbol {b}=(b_1,\cdots,b_n)^{T}$.

$\Vert \boldsymbol {b}\Vert=\Vert A^{-1}\boldsymbol {z}\Vert\le \Vert A^{-1}\Vert \Vert \boldsymbol {z}\Vert$
where $\Vert A^{-1}\Vert=\mathrm{sup}_{\Vert \boldsymbol {x}\Vert=1}=\Vert A^{-1}\boldsymbol {x}\Vert$.

Comment: But how do you estimate the matrix norm of $A^{-1}$ in terms of $c$?